# Python replace with regex

Tags: python, regex

I have two strings which contains the following substrings: `myStringA` and `myStringBB;` and a dictionary `d` which maps `A` and `BB` to some other values, lets say `d["A"] = "X"` and `d["BB"] = "YY"`. I want to replace both of these strings by the following strings:

`ThisIsMyStringX` and `ThisIsMyStringYY;`. So that I want to replace `A` and `BB` (which are known for me) by the values from dictionary and leave `;` if present at the end and add `ThisIs` and the beginning. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Use `re.sub()` with a function as the replacement. The function can look up the match in the dictionary.

Comment: Does this answer your question? "[Advanced string replacements in python](/q/26844742/90527)", "[Mass string replace in python?](/q/1919096/90527)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex match-groups to achieve these replacements (a Match group is a Part of an regex encapsulated by brackets). For example:

```
import re

regex=re.compile("foo(bar)")
match = regex.match("foobar")
print(match.group(1))
```

will print "bar".
Here ist a working programm that solves your specific Problem:

```
import re

dict = {
   "A": "X",
   "BB": "YY"
}
myStringA = "myStringA"
myStringBB = "myStringBB"

regex = re.compile("my(\w+)(A|BB)")

match = regex.match(myStringA)
print("ThisIsMy"+ match.group(1) + 
dict[match.group(2)])

match = regex.match(myStringBB)
print("ThisIsMy"+ match.group(1) + 
dict[match.group(2)])
```